# Unable to create call adapter for retrofit2.Response<...>

Tags: android, retrofit2, moshi

My Api:

```
@GET("/cinema/notShownMovies")
fun getNotShownMovies(
   @Query("token") token: String
): Response<GetMovieResponse>
```

**Exception when trying to call API:**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for
> retrofit2.Response<...data.GetMovieResponse>
> for method InstanceApi.getNotShownMovies Unable to create call adapter for retrofit2.Response<...data.GetMovieResponse>
> for method InstanceApi.getNotShownMovies

I don't know where to start. All other API calls work fine which is also defined in the same API class. Maybe a model error?

Comment: How you create ApiService?

Comment: Your other methods that work in the service are wrapped in `Response<>` or `Call<>`?

Comment: val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        return retrofit.create(Api::class.java)

Comment: All methods are wrapped with `Response<>`

Comment: Also, why are you using `Response<GetMovieResponse>` instead of `Response<Movie>`?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Just add `suspend` modifier if using `coroutines`. This will solve the problem.

Otherwise your issue is likely because there is no Call adapter added when instantiating your `Retrofit` object.
For example, for `RxJava2`, you can include a call adapter by adding this line while building it.

```
.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
```

Comment: I am using kotlin coroutines so why would I need RxJava? Furthermore, this does not explain why it is working on all other calls.

Comment: If you're using coroutines, then include keyword `suspend` before your function. I also believe you simply need to wrap your data class in `Response`.

Comment: Yeah this error message is not helpful at all in identifying a missing `suspend`.

Comment: Missing the suspend for this API, thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot,,,,, I have tried full day, Its missing of *Suspend* for api function

Comment: @SuhadBinZubair I had the same issue missing suspend on the retrofit API call.  Did that and it worked perfect.

Comment: Yeah it works great. I tried a lot and changed my retrofit implementation to enque method.

Comment: Why does adding the suspend keyword fix it? They seem very unrelated...but if it does the trick...

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar crash `IllegalArgumentException: Call return type must be parameterized as Call`.

Crash log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for interface retrofit2.Call
    for method Api.login
    at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:54)
    at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createCallAdapter(HttpServiceMethod.java:116)
    at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(HttpServiceMethod.java:67)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:39)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:202)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:160)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
    at $Proxy0.login(Unknown Source)
    at <redacted>.screen.login.LoginActivity.onSignInClick(LoginActivity.java:103)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Call return type must be parameterized as Call<Foo> or Call<? extends Foo>
    at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory.get(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:42)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Retrofit.java:253)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter(Retrofit.java:237)
    at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createCallAdapter(HttpServiceMethod.java:114)
    ... 20 more
```

I found out it was crashing because of Proguard/R8. Proguard was renaming Retrofit classes and to fix it I updated the Proguard settings with:

```
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
```

Comment: It did solve the problem for crashing, but I am started facing problem adapters. For example I see same item getting displayed multiple times.

Comment: It solved :) When I updated my app last December than I haven't faced this issue that time.  Today I need to add 2 Progard Rules. Don't know why?

Comment: @Arpit I get the same issue of items being displayed multiple times. How did you fix?

Comment: There are some proguard rules need to define for gson @DayemSaeed please check that

Comment: My `proguard-rules` file had retrofit rules but without the `2` and your comment saved my life  Such a little detail brought me so much trouble...

Comment: Thank you! This code was working on my computer (debug) but when built for release (which uses proguard) it was crashing - thanks for this tip!

Answer (score -4):

In the Gradle file add this line inside of release buildTyps

- minifyEnabled false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).