# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for retrofit2.Response<java.lang.Object>

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sunbots.mvvmdemo, PID: 11417
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for retrofit2.Response<java.lang.Object>
for method ApiCalls.apiCallForCheckSponsorAvailable
at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:54)
at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createCallAdapter(HttpServiceMethod.java:116)
at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(HttpServiceMethod.java:67)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:39)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:202)
at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:160)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
at $Proxy2.apiCallForCheckSponsorAvailable(Unknown Source)
at com.sunbots.mvvmdemo.data.remote.repository.SponsorRepository$apiCallForCheckSponsor$2.invokeSuspend(SponsorRepository.kt:9)
at com.sunbots.mvvmdemo.data.remote.repository.SponsorRepository$apiCallForCheckSponsor$2.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
at com.sunbots.mvvmdemo.data.remote.repository.SponsorRepository$apiCallForCheckSponsor$2.invoke(Unknown Source:2)
at com.sunbots.mvvmdemo.data.remote.api.ApiRequestResponse.apiRequest(ApiRequestResponse.kt:13)
at com.sunbots.mvvmdemo.data.remote.repository.SponsorRepository.apiCallForCheckSponsor(SponsorRepository.kt:8)
at com.sunbots.mvvmdemo.viewmodel.ViewModelSponsor$apiCallForCheckSponsor$1.invokeSuspend(ViewModelSponsor.kt:15)
at com.sunbots.mvvmdemo.viewmodel.ViewModelSponsor$apiCallForCheckSponsor$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
at com.sunbots.mvvmdemo.viewmodel.ViewModelSponsor$apiCallForCheckSponsor$1.invoke(Unknown Source:2)
at com.sunbots.mvvmdemo.data.remote.api.Coroutines$ioThenMain$1$data$1.invokeSuspend(Coroutines.kt:9)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:100)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@f39fd31, Dispatchers.Main]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate call adapter for retrofit2.Response<java.lang.Object>.
Tried:
* retrofit2.CompletableFutureCallAdapterFactory
* retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory
at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Retrofit.java:272)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.callAdapter(Retrofit.java:237)
at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createCallAdapter(HttpServiceMethod.java:114)
... 23 more

api calling were not success

Comment: Check this issue. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62464914

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.